# Display message IF forwarded from other domain

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, popup, http-status-code-301

So, just a question on if this is possible.

I am using a 301 redirect from the old site to the new one, but those can be a bit jarring for users. SO, I had a though. Can I get users to see a message if they are forwarded from an older domain name? Like so:

1) They visit the new site, they see just the site. 
2) They visit the old site, they get forwarded to the new site AND on the new site they get a popup explaining the old site is dead and this is the new one.

Is that possible??

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do your `301 rule` like this:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?olddomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com%{REQUEST_URI}?redir=1 [R=301,L,NE,QSA]
```

Now on `newdomain.com` page just check for `?redir=1` in URLs, if it is found then show appropriate popup message to user.

Comment: I think the example above is for apache, but the concept should work for different servers as well, such as IIS.

Comment: Yes that's true this rewrite rule should work for other web servers also.

Comment: Thanks very much Anubhava, I'm putting that in now and it seems to be great!